# SQL SELECT . Rows to columns

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table with two fields.
The 1st is a 'key' and the 2nd field can have only value 'A' or 'B'.
I would like, with a SELECT, to retrieve a recordset that, grouping by the 1st field, have two columns with the count of the values of the 2nd field.

Table:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | B |

Result:

| Key | Counf of A | Counf of B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: at a very quick glance you should be able to do this with SUM and GROUP BY .  Take a look at a tutorial like this https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-sum-group-by/

Comment: Use conditional aggregation. Please include your attempt even though it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Key,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Value = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Count of A",
    SUM(CASE WHEN Value = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Count of B"
FROM
    {TABLE_NAME} // Replace 'TABLE_NAME' with the name of your table
GROUP BY
    Key;
```

Comment: Ok, that's what I need. I thought was something like that but I was missing the "CASE WHEN" statement. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL (as it's taged in your question), you don't need `CASE`.

The query will simply be:

```
SELECT
  `Key`,
  SUM(`Value` = 'A') AS `Count of A`,
  SUM(`Value` = 'B') AS `Count of B`
FROM
  test
GROUP BY
  `Key`;
```

If your RDBMS does not support above query, I would prefer `COUNT` here over `SUM`.

`COUNT` returns zero if only `NULL` appears.

Therefore the `CASE` doesn't require an `ELSE` clause, so it's more readable.

```
SELECT
  `Key`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN `Value` = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS `Count of A`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN `Value` = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS `Count of B`
FROM
  test
GROUP BY
  `Key`;
```

See this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/li_xrI5p)